# Android, How return result from fragment activity to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment in my fragment activity. 
In order to show fragment dialog, I have an interface in my fragment which has been implemented in fragment activity.
So far there is no problem. I can pop-up dialog. Fragment activity is able to get OK/Cancel buttons When user hit it.

Now, my question is, is there any way (alternative way rather than creating another interface in fragment activity and implement it in fragment) to let fragment know OK/Cancel clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your activity should know which fragments it uses you can easily get your fragment, cast it to it's real class (if you don't want a new interface) and call a public method of it:

```
ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

if (articleFrag != null) {
            // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

            // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

            // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
            ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
            newFragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
```

Note: This code is taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).